# pandas read excel: do not parse numbers

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am working with python pandas and MS excel to edit a xlsx file. I iterate between these programs back and forth. The file contains some columns with text that looks like numbers, e.g.,

[image]

If I read this, I get

```
pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx')
     A
0    1
1  100
```

and

```
pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx').dtypes
A    int64
dtype: object
```

My question is: how is it possible to read the text as text? It is not an option to parse it back after reading, because part of the information (i.e., the leading zeros) is lost upon conversion to a number.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Working with csv would be easy. Any reason for excel file only?

Comment: Because I had numerous issues sharing csv between excel and python, in particular if some cells contain non-ascii characters. With xls or xlsx files, this character encoding issue does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5891), it's a known problem with pandas.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer (it's a first for me :). You mention having encoding issues with CSVs. You should ask about that, because I think those are solvable.

Answer (score 19):

You can work around the [known issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5891) (assuming that you know the column name) by using the 'converters' parameter:

```
>>> pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', converters={'A': str})
     A
0  001
1  100
>>> pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', converters={'A': str}).dtypes
A    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: As of pandas 0.20 you can control dtypes directly.

Comment: is it possible to convert column index 0:5?

Answer (score 4):

if you're able to convert the file to CSV, dtype=str should work.

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=str)
```

Source:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html